# Multiprocessing does not work when first running the same code single-threaded

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing

I am currently trying to parallelize a part of an existing program, and have encountered a strange behaviour that causes my program to stop execution (it is still running, but does not make any further progress).

First, here is a minimal working example:

```py
import multiprocessing
import torch

def foo(x):
    print(x)
    return torch.zeros(x, x)

size = 200

# first block
print("Run with single core")
res = []
for i in range(size):
    res.append(foo(i))

# second block
print("Run with multiprocessing")
data = [i for i in range(size)]
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1) as pool:
    res = pool.map(foo, data)
```

The problem is that the script stops running during multiprocessing, and reliably at `x = 182`. Up to this point, I could come up with some reasonable explanations, but now comes the strange part: If I run the code only in parallel (so only the second block of code), the script works perfectly fine. It also works if I first run the parallel version, and then the single-threaded code. Only at the moment where I first run the first and then the second block, the program gets stuck. This holds also true, if I first run the second block, then the first one, and then the second one again; in that case, the first multiprocessing block works fine, and it gets stuck, the second time I run the multiprocessing version.

The problem seems not to stem from a lack of memory, since I can increase size to much higher values (1000+) when only running the multiprocessing code. Additionally, I have no problem when I use `np.zeros((x, x))` instead of `torch.zeros`. Removing the print function does not help either, so I kept it in for demonstration purposes.

This was also reproducible on other machines, stopping as well at `x = 182` when running both blocks, but working fine when only running the second. Python and Pytorch versions were respectively (3.7.3, 1.7.1), (3.8.9, 1.8.1), and (3.8.5, 1.9.0). All systems were Ubuntu based.

Has someone an explanation for this behaviour or did I miss any parameters/options I need to set for this to work?

Comment: (1) wrap the boot code in a `main()` method (it's good form with `multiprocessing`) (2) since you're on Linux, try a different start method (`multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')`?

Comment: I'd like to expand on @AKX's answer with the reasoning.  When you use `multiprocessing`, that starts a brand-new interpreter in a brand-new process.  That interpreter has to reload your main module (but with `__name__` set to something else).  So, any global code that you have in your file is going to be run AGAIN in the new process.  In your case, that's going to run the single core test AGAIN, and then run `multiprocessing` AGAIN.  You MUST put your global code inside an `if __name__=='__main__':` block to protect against this.

Comment: (Unless you're using the `fork` start method, in which case things won't be run again)

Comment: Thank you so much! While the first point (setting the name to `__main__`) did not help, and I also only left this out for the MWE, setting the start method solved my problem (I will surely have a look today why this needs to be done). Nonetheless, it is interesting to know that multiprocessing creates its own `__name__`.